# higher order polynomials

Tags: polynomials, cubics

Suppose all the roots of the equation $x^3+bx-2017=0$
 (where $b \in \mathbb{R}$) are real. Prove that exactly one root is positive.
My progress:

- As product of three roots is $2017$ which is positive integer. (then possibilities are either any two are negative and 1 is positive or all three are positive.)
- And the sum of three roots is $0$. (which means either all of them are zero or few are negative and positive later one is not possible as $0$ is not solution to above problem and product of roots is $2017$)
- I also found out that $b<0$.
  From above three we can say that one root has to be positive. Am I correct?

Is there any other way of doing above problem? I am sure I can find one here.

Thank you

Comment: And please if you down vote any problem then at least tell the reason for doing so.So that someone who is NEW won't repeat that mistake in future.

Comment: I did not downvote it (I upvoted to compensate because your question shows research effort), but I guess that the reasons were 1) mathematical formulas are not typeset correctly (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) and 2) the meaning of some sentences is not clear

Comment: Maybe the downvoter thought you should have known about [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the graph of $f(x)=x^3+bx-2017$.

Let the roots of $f$ be $r_1 < r_2 < r_3$.

Since $f(0)<0$, we have $0 \in (-\infty,r_1) \cup (r_2,r_3)$.

Since $r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = 0$, we have $r_1 < 0$ and so $0 \in (r_2,r_3)$.

This means that $r_1 < r_2 < 0 < r_3$ and so $r_3$ is the only positive root.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. The product of the roots is positive, hence at least one is positive (because there are three of them). Their sum is zero, so this implies that at least one root is negative. Again, since the product is positive, the only possibility is that one is positive and the other two are negative.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. Here is another one:

By Descartes’ rule of signs, there is exactly one sign change in the polynomial (irrespective of what $b$ is), so it has exactly one positive root.

*Notice we didn’t have to use the fact that all roots are real, all we needed was $b\in \mathbb R$.*